# How to send a color text mail through php?

Tags: php, email, text, colors

I have a contact form and I use to send mail through php.
But I want to put to line in the end of the mail in red color.
I don't want HTML mail. Just only two lines want to make in red.
Anyone can help me?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to specify colours, you MUST use HTML - no other way around it.

Answer (score 0):

you need to send a html mail... else you can't send a mail with red text

Answer (score 0):

in other words, plain text doesn't support any formatting including colors.